# What's the density of $Z=\max(X,Y)-\min(X,Y)$ with $X,Y$ exponentials of parameter $\lambda$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-function, convolution

Let be $X,Y$ two independent exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$. What is the pdf of $Z=\max(X,Y)-\min(X,Y)$? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A less elegant but equally valid approach is to note that we may equivalently write $$Z = |X - Y|,$$ so that $$\begin{align*} f_Z(z) &= \int_{y=0}^\infty f_X(y+z)f_Y(y) \, dy + \int_{y=z}^\infty f_X(y-z)f_Y(y) \, dy \\ &= \int_{y=0}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda(y+z)} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \, dy + \int_{y=z}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda(y-z)} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \, dy \\ &= \lambda e^{-\lambda z}.\end{align*}$$

Comment: less elegant but more useful to me. thank you

Answer (score 4):

By symmetry we can assume that $X\lt Y$, so $Z=Y-X$. Now from the memorylessness of the exponential, we have that given that $Y\gt X$, the distribution of $Y-X$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: could you be clearer regarding the memoryless property in this case? and does the difference of 2 eponentials(λ) r.v's still is an exp(λ)? how come? thank you

Comment: The difference $Y-X$ cannot be exponentially distributed since then you would have $\Pr(Y-X\ge0)>0$, and clearly that is false.  This is actually the _conditional_ distribution given the event $X<Y$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The difference of two exponentials is not exponential. But **given** that $Y\gt X$, the "additional waiting time" for $Y$ (that is, $Y-X$) has exponential distribution parameter $\lambda$. This is because in general, if $Y\ge t_0$ (we have waited for an amount of time $t_0$) the additional waiting time has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. If one wants to do it by a computation, the conditional probability that $Y\gt t+t_0$ given that $Y\gt t_0$ is $\frac{e^{-\lambda(t+t_0)}}{e^{-\lambda t_0}}$. This simplifies to $e^{-\lambda t}$.